# auth0-deploy cli - a0deploy: command not found

Tags: node-modules, auth0, auth0-deploy-cli

Trying to integrate auth0 and gitlab. Installed auth0-deploy-cli (npm i auth0-deploy-cli). When trying to export using a0deploy export command, getting command not found: a0deploy.(node version is 16)

Answer (score 0):

You should have found the answer, but for others who should have the same question, you just have to add the path in your environment variables (at least on windows).

The app is here : `C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\npm`

Then, restart your terminal.
It should work.